# Cyclic Quartic Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a real cyclic "quartic" number field $K$ with the unique quadratic subfield $F$. I am wondering if it is possible to explicitly write down a unit $u\in\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ by "only using the information in $F$" (**Means that you can take n-th root, any algebraic operation or evaluate special function at some points in $F$ or etc.**) such that $$K=\mathbb{Q}(u).$$ Thank you!

Comment: What does "the" unit in $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$ mean? The rank of the unit group is $3$ if $K$ is real. Are you assuming $K$ is not real? In that case, the rank of the unit group is $1$, as is the rank of the unit group of $F$. Under this assumption, let $\varepsilon_F$ be the fundamental unit of $F$ and $\varepsilon_K$ the fundamental unity of $K$. By looking at the Galois action, either $\varepsilon_F = \pm \varepsilon_K$ or $\varepsilon_F = \pm \varepsilon^2_F$. Which one is which depends on $K$ in an obvious way.

Comment: I fixed it! thank you

Comment: "only using the information in $F$'' is hopelessly vague. $F$ doesn't even determine $K$. Explain what you actually want.

Comment: @Infinity No problem! I explain on the above.

Comment: This doesn't address my comment. If you "only use information in $F$" you can't even determine what $K$ actually is --- there will be many such $K$ containing $F$. And once you determine $K$, it's easy enough to write down units in abelian extensions without even making use of $u$ by taking norms of circular units. This is not a real question until it is formulated in a manner in which is possible to attach precise meaning to a "yes" or "no" answer.